# Add Custom Validation Rule in existing street field of shipping address form Checkout Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

Basically I am trying to add custom validation rule in existing street field of shipping address form Checkout in magento 2 where pobox should not be allowed. I tried using mixin with requirejs-config.js which works well as it gets called till **(console.log(hello))** but I am not sure why my '**validate-street-part**' is not getting called from layoutprocessor and adding '**validate-street-part**' to **(mage/validation.js)**. Any advise or suggestion would be appreciated.

**`\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Magento_Checkout\web\js\pobox-mixin.js`**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
   'mage/translate'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        console.log("hello");
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-street-part',
            function (v) {
                var pattern = /^([post]*)$/.test(v);
                console.log(pattern);
                if(!pattern){ 
                    console.log("return true");
                    return true;
                }else{
                    console.log("return false");
                    return false; 
                }
            },
            $.mage.__("Please note that we cannot ship to PO Boxes. Please enter a physical address.")
        );
    };
});
```

**`app\design\frontend\Vendor\Magento_Checkout\requirejs-config.js`**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
'mage/validation': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/pobox-mixin' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**`app\code\Vendor\Checkout\etc\di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="rewrite-street" type="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**`app\code\Vendor\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['validation']['validate-street-part'] = 1;

return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have missed '[children]' after '[street]' and before '[validation]'. Also you can assign 'true' instead of '1'
It should be like below

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children']['validation']['validate-street-part'] = true;
```

If you have any confusion in array keys and values, you can log below array.

```
print_r($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']);
```

Sample code for street validation

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
                ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'] 
                ['children']['street'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                    'label' => __('Street Address'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'sortOrder' => 4,
                    'type' => 'group',
                    'config' => [        
                        'template' => 'ui/group/group',
                        'additionalClasses' => 'street'
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        [
                            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                            'config' => [
                                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                            ],
                            'dataScope' => '0',
                            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                            'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255, "validate-street-part" => true],
                            'additionalClasses' => 'field',
                            'label' => __('Street 1')
                        ],
                        [
                            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                            'config' => [
                                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                            ],
                            'dataScope' => '1',
                            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                            'validation' => ["min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255,"validate-street-part" => true],
                            'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                            'label' => __('Street 2')
                        ]

                    ]];
```

Comment: I am also facing same issues. above code is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

**`app\design\frontend\Vendor\Magento_Checkout\web\js\pobox-mixin.js`**

```
 define([  
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
        'jquery',
         'jquery/ui',
         'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate',
    ], function (validator,$) {
        "use strict";

        return function () {

            validator.addRule(
            'validate-street-part',function(v){
                var pattern = /((((p[\s\.]?)\s?[o\s][\.]?)\s?)|(post\s?office\s?))((box|bin|b\.?)?\s?((num|number|no|#)\.?)?\s?\d+)/igm.test(v);

                if(!pattern){ 
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false; 
                }
            },
            $.mage.__("Please note that we cannot ship to PO Boxes. Please enter a physical address.")
            );
        };
    });
```

In the previous code I was using addMethod I used addRule instead and passed validator. I added `'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'` which is really important because I assume validator was not defined in mixin so it was unable to read though I was having `jquery/validate`. Also I made sure the order of defining files in mixin at the top follows certain order as I have in my answer cause some functionality of validator might be overriding or there could be a case where rule will be added to the orginal validator and later create another validator for adding custom rule. And other change has been posted by @MathewLawrence which is valid for layout processor. Thanks for contributing